# CHIP-8 emulator in Python not rendering

Tags: python

I'm building a CHIP-8 emulator (or interpreter) in Python using Pygame. However, when I finished with adding all the instructions and tried rendering the IBM logo, I get nothing.

After doing some investigating, I see that the render command isn't even being called.

The part of code that is responsible for rendering:

```py
def drw_vx_vy(self):
    width = 8
    height = self.opcode & 0xF
    print("drw")

    self.v[0xF] = 0

    for row in range(height):
        sprite = self.memory[self.i + row]

        for col in range(width):
            if (sprite & 0x80) > 0:
                self.display.draw_pixel(self.v[self.x] + col, self.v[self.y] + row)
                self.v[0xF] = 1

            sprite = sprite << 1
```

Code that is responsible for rendering pixels in the `Display` class:

```py
def draw_pixel(self, x, y):
    if x > self.width:
        x -= self.width
    elif x < 0:
        x += self.width

    if y > self.height:
        x -= self.height
    elif x < 0:
        x += self.height
    
    pixelLoc = x + (y * self.height)
    self.pixels[pixelLoc] = self.pixels[pixelLoc] ^ 1
    print(self.pixels[pixelLoc])

    return not self.pixels[pixelLoc]

    # pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, (255,255,255), (
    #     x * self.scale, y * self.scale, self.scale, self.scale)
    # )

def clear_display(self):
    self.screen.fill((0,0,0))

def render(self):
    self.clear_display()
    for i in range(self.width * self.height):
        x = (i % self.width) * self.scale
        y = i / self.width * self.scale

        if self.pixels[i]:
            pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, (255,255,255), (
                x, y, self.scale, self.scale)
            )

    pygame.display.update()
```

I have checked to see if I put the function in the wrong case statement, but that isn't the case either. I am following this guide, if it is of any help (the guide is in JavaScript but I adapted it to Python): https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/creating-your-very-own-chip-8-emulator/

Comment: If this code isn't even called, then it is very unlikely that this is where the bug is. Show us a [mcve].

Comment: @user2357112 I don't know how I am supposed to make a minimal reproducible example for an entire emulator where everything depends on each other. If you want, I could put the code on GH for better investigating.

Comment: There are two primary approaches: a top-down approach, tearing out giant chunks of your program until the problem goes away and putting back anything that turned out to be necessary to reproduce the error, or a bottom-up approach, starting from basic bits you think you understand and putting pieces together until something goes wrong. What you post doesn't have to reproduce the functionality of your emulator; it just has to reproduce the bug.

Comment: Ah I think I get your point now

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: "After doing some investigating, I see that the render command isn't even being called." Okay, so, **work backwards from there**. I assume that by "the render command", you mean the `draw_pixel` function; and that you expect it to be called from `self.display.draw_pixel(self.v[self.x] + col, self.v[self.y] + row)`. Well, that's inside an `if` block, right? **Did you try to check** the value of `sprite` at this point in the program, and thus whether `(sprite & 0x80) > 0`? How about the values of `width` and `height` (since they will determine the number of loop iterations)?

Comment: Unless by "the render command" you actually indeed meant the function named `render`, in which case *I don't understand how the example is supposed to illustrate the problem*. In particular: what part of this code do you expect to call `render`; why; and how? I don't see `render` anywhere in the posted code **except for** the `def` line.

Comment: Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and [mre], and note well that this is not a debugging service, nor a discussion forum. We won't use the answer section here to help you find a bug; it is your responsibility to find it, in order to **ask a question** about **why** the bug is a bug, or about **how** to circumvent it. We want to build a **searchable library** of questions. "Where is the bug?" cannot be searched and cannot help others, because nobody else has the same bug in the same code as you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally figured it out. Here are a list of changes I've made:

- I've simplified the renderer to a point that I can understand:

```py
def draw_pixel(self, x, y):
    if x > self.width:
        x -= self.width
    elif x < 0:
        x += self.width

    if y > self.height:
        x -= self.height
    elif x < 0:
        x += self.height
    
    self.pixels.append((x, y))

    return not self.pixels[len(self.pixels) - 1]

def clear_display(self):
    self.screen.fill((0,0,0))

def render(self):
    self.clear_display()
    for i in range(len(self.pixels)):
        pixel = self.pixels[i]
        x = pixel[0]
        y = pixel[1]

        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (255,255,255), (
            x * self.scale, y * self.scale, self.scale, self.scale)
        )

    pygame.display.update()
```

- `height` in `drw_vx_vy` is now `self.opcode & 0x000F` (actually getting the last nibble)

And the final nail in the coffin, was the use of the `or` keyword rather than the `|` operator when decoding the opcode. Keep in mind I'm more used to Python than JavaScript (the language the guide was written in), and I'd totally forgotten that `||` was `or`, not `|`.

```py
opcode = (self.memory[self.pc] << 8 | self.memory[self.pc + 1])
```